# Codeigniter session data destroy after save

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I  am using session value in to my form  set_value . I want destroy the set_value after the form  successfully save

```
$vv=$this->session->userdata;
$reason=$vv['reason'];


<textarea id="present"  name="reason" class="form-control " required rows="6"> <?php echo set_value('reason',$reason); ?> </textarea>
```

Comment: add some code to your question

Comment: Its relay cant understand what you trying to do?? and what you want?? Simply **Unclear what you are asking about !!!** For the help [Read The Codeigniter Session](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: i want to destroy session value after the from submitted

Comment: if user enter wrong data and validate and back to view it will show error in session variable. so after insert details success then destroy it

Answer (score 0):

Just use unset to Remove any session value.

```
unset($_SESSION['xyz']);
```

In-case of codeignitor, you can use:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('xyz');
```